# Sending and receiving OOB data through a TCP connection using POCO C++

Tags: c++, tcpserver, poco-libraries

I need to develop a TCP server capable of receiving periodic urgent out-of-bounds data. I am using the POCO C++ libraries to achieve this. In the (scarce) documentation of the [StreamSocket](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.StreamSocket.html) class, I see that this should be a very easy task to achieve: it should be done by setting the SO_OOBINLINE flag when using the receiveBytes() method like so:

```
n = ss.receiveBytes( buffer, sizeof(buffer), SO_OOBINLINE );
```

To test this, I made a very simple TCP client (also using the POCO libraries) which uses the "sendUrgent()" method to send the OOB data (a single byte):

```
ss1.sendUrgent( 0xFF );
```

When I send the OOB data, nothing happens. The server doesn't seem to notice it.

On the other hand, when I send "normal" data, using the sendBytes() method, if the SO_OOBINLINE flag is set on the StreamSocket, I receive an infinite amount of the same sent data (it keeps reading the same data although nobody is resending it).

What am I missing?

**Edit**: After @JimR's suggestion and reading [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6coobd.htm), I have tried:

```
n = ss.receiveBytes( buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_OOB );
```

And even this:

```
n = ss.receiveBytes( buffer, sizeof(buffer), SO_OOBINLINE | MSG_OOB );
```

Both raise the same exception: Invalid argument.

Comment: `SO_OOBINLINE` tells the socket to return OOB data in regular reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* (it's been a long time) you should change

`n = ss.receiveBytes( buffer, sizeof(buffer), SO_OOBINLINE );` to

`n = ss.receiveBytes( buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_OOB );`

*Edit*: Along with the above changes, you will need to call `setsockopt` with the `SO_OOBINLINE` flag and the appropriate arguments so OOB data will be seen in the normal stream and not in a separate channel.  In your case, as stated in the comments, call `ss.setOOBInline(true);`.

`SO_OOBINLINE` is a socket option used with `setsockopt`.

`MSG_OOB` is a flag for `recv` and `send` and company.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I make this change, the _receiveBytes_ method throws an exception: "Invalid argument". The documentation of the _sendUrgent_ method says the following:

"Sends one byte of urgent data through the socket.
The data is sent with the MSG_OOB flag.
The preferred way for a socket to receive urgent data is by enabling the SO_OOBINLINE option".

Comment: @pparescasellas: Agreed that `SO_OOBINLINE` is preferred, but...  Unless POCO is changing the meaning, the only mention of `SO_OOBINLINE` in the Linux source is related to calls to `setsockopt` and company and its definition.  You can see for yourself here: http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/ident?a=sparc64;i=SO_OOBINLINE

Comment: @pparescasellas: Something just occurred to me, I figured I'd mention it.  Did you use setsockopt to add the `SO_OOB_INLINE` option to the socket before using MSG_OOB?  If not, that may be why you're getting the exception...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have two different programs: one that acts as the server (and has the SO_OOBINLINE flag at the receiveBytes method) and another one that acts as a client (and has the sendUrgent method, which uses the MSG_OOB flag internally). So yeah, I first run the server and, when it's running, I run the client to establish the connection and send OOB data. Once the connection is established and the server reaches the "receiveBytes" method, the exception is thrown (if I make your change and use MSG_OOB on the server side).

Comment: @pparescasellas: Look at the documentation for the function `setsockopt` (Or whatever POCO calls it) and it should become clear.

Comment: Ok, I found it. You have to call a function called "setOOBInline" before the "receiveBytes" one. It doesn't work if you specify the flag directly into the "receiveBytes" method. So, ss.setOOBInline(true); n = ss.receiveBytes(...).
I was about to answer my own question and accept it but since this is more or lees what you said on the comments, if you modify your answer with this, I'll accept it ;).

Comment: Are you going to edit your answer so I can accept it? I'll answer and accept it myself if you don't want to.

Comment: @pparescasellas: I edited it on Sept. 17.  I just now marked it with Edit: